# Max-Min Parents and Children feature selection techniquer

Tags: r

I run Feature selection Max-Min Parents and Children with the MMPC algorithm from the MXM library and i got this error :
Error in cor(target, dataset) : 'x' must be numeric

NB: Cardio1M is a factor variable with 6 levels and data is a dataset of factor and numerical variable

```
mxres<-MMPC(data$Cardio1M,data[,-72],max_k = 3, threshold = 0.05,test = 'testIndFisher')
```

Answer (score -1):

it works when i changed the class of the target variable to numeric as below
data$Cardio1M<-ifelse(data$Cardio1M=="anomalous",1,0)
 and i am not convienced because in the documentation( https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MXM/versions/0.9.7/topics/The%20max-min%20Markov%20blanket%20algorithm) it is possible for the class variable to be either a string, an integer, a numeric value, a vector, a factor, an ordered factor or a Surv object. 
Any explanation